# Troposphere template for Cloudfront using S3 website origin

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to automate the deployment of a static website. I have a static website (angular/javascript/html) sitting in a bucket, and need to use the AWS Cloudfront CDN.

```
   s3dnsname = self.template.add_parameter(Parameter(
        "S3DNSName",
        Description="The DNS name of an existing S3 bucket to use as the "
                    "Cloudfront distribution origin",
        Type="String",
    ))

    myDistribution = self.template.add_resource(Distribution(
        "myDistribution",
        DistributionConfig=DistributionConfig(
            Origins=[Origin(Id="Origin 1", DomainName=Ref(s3dnsname),
                            S3OriginConfig=S3Origin())],
            DefaultCacheBehavior=DefaultCacheBehavior(
                TargetOriginId="Origin 1",
                ForwardedValues=ForwardedValues(
                    QueryString=False
                ),
                ViewerProtocolPolicy="allow-all"),
            Enabled=True,
            HttpVersion='http2'

        )
    ))
```

This is my code and I am getting an error "The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket."

I looked into several articles/blogs on this and they all point to adding the following:

```
custom_origin_config { 
    origin_protocol_policy = "http-only" 
    http_port              = 80 
    https_port             = 443 
    origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1"] 
}
```

Can anyone please point me to where I need to add this part?

Update:
I tried to replace S3OriginConfig with CustomOriginConfig below like this:

```
   myDistribution = self.template.add_resource(Distribution(
        "myDistribution",
        DistributionConfig=DistributionConfig(
            Origins=[Origin(
                Id="Origin 1",
                DomainName=Ref(s3dnsname),
                CustomOriginConfig=CustomOriginConfig(
                    OriginProtocolPolicy="http-only",
                    HTTPPort=80,
                    HTTPSPort=443))],
            DefaultCacheBehavior=DefaultCacheBehavior(
                TargetOriginId="Origin 1",
                ForwardedValues=ForwardedValues(
                    QueryString=False
                ),
                ViewerProtocolPolicy="allow-all"),
            Enabled=True,
            HttpVersion='http2'
        )
    ))
```

After running this, I get an error "NameError: global name 'CustomOriginConfig' is not defined"

I am missing something here which I am not able to identify.

Comment: That is not cloudformation. Perhaps terraform?

Comment: @chris : Yes kind of. I will refer this .py template in a .yaml file where I pass all the variable data. Then run that .yaml file for the stack creation using cloudformation.

This .py file is converted from CloudFront_S3.template located at: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-templates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
from troposphere.cloudfront import S3Origin, CustomOrigin
```

And changed the code to:

```
Origins=[Origin(Id="Origin 1", DomainName=Ref(s3dnsname),
                            CustomOriginConfig=CustomOrigin(
                                HTTPPort=80,
                                HTTPSPort=443,
                                OriginProtocolPolicy="http-only"
                            ))],
```

I am using this example: https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/examples/CloudFront_S3.py

Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue.